# Why is what was /dev/md1 when I created it now apparently called /dev/md127 or /dev/md127p1?

Tags: debian, mdadm, software-raid

I recently installed a new Debian 9 ("stretch") machine.

Initally it had 2 drives. I configured them as RAID1 using the Debian installer, and it gave me a `/dev/md0` with

```
/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf:
```

containing

```
# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=3d21d0e0:2758c58e:962b5191:98e225c1 name=MYHOSTNAME:0
```

and `/proc/mdstat` showing:

```
md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      488253440 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/4 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

That device I formatted as `ext4` and mounted by UUID as '/' in `/etc/fstab`).  All works fine, as expected.

Later I added a couple more even bigger drives. Partitioned them (with a small swap parition on each first) and configured them using `mdadm -C -n 2 -l raid1 /dev/md1 /dev/sdc2 /dev/sdd2` (that's definitely what I did because it's still in my root's shell history, along with a couple of subsequent `mdadm --examine /dev/md1` and `mdadm --detail --verbose /dev/md1`).

I also added a line to `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` (just following the pattern for the initial device):

```
ARRAY /dev/md/1  metadata=1.2 UUID=47492bd7:08d1fd1c:418dad41:2aa7d77f name=MYHOSTNAME:1
```

And of course I `ext4` formatted the device and added a UUID entry to `/etc/fstab` to mount this at my chosen `/data` mount point.

That all seems to be working fine, and after multiple reboots of the machine too, and I have happily been doing huge rsyncs to the new disks.

However today I happened to glance at etc/mtab and /proc/mdstat and I notice my /dev/md1 seems to have disappeared and morphed into a /dev/md127 (in /proc/mdstat) and/or a /dev/md127p1 in /etc/mtab:

```
/proc/mdstat:
```

shows:

```
md127 : active raid1 sdc2[0] sdd2[1]
      3904788480 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 2/30 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      488253440 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/4 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

and

```
/etc/mtab:
```

shows:

```
/dev/md0 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/md127p1 /data ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
```

It all still seems to be working fine, but what the heck happened there? I've configured RAID1 in much the same way on a couple of other machines before (admittedly many years ago) and there the RAID arrays just ended up called `/dev/md0` and `/dev/md1`.  Where did this `127` come from and what's the difference between `/dev/md127` and `/dev/md127p1`?  Is there some way I can rename them to `/dev/md1`, or is this something I'm stuck with?

Comment: Is your `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`, specifically the `/dev/md/1` line, still the same? And does the UUID listed there still match your `md1`? The 127 thing is when MDRAID gets confused for some reason, and thinks you might get a numbering conflict with the existing arrays, so it starts numbering backwards. 127 is the maximum, I think. But this can happen for different reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the following command to make sure you are dealing with the right UUIDs:

   ```
   mdadm --detail /dev/md* | grep -e /dev/md -e UUID
   ```
2. Edit your arrays list, you can use nano if unsure:

   ```
   nano /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
   ```

   for it to contain the UUIDs of arrays you want; or double-check it:

   > ```
   > ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 name=MYHOSTNAME:0 UUID=3d21d0e0:2758c58e:962b5191:98e225c1
   > ARRAY /dev/md/1 metadata=1.2 name=MYHOSTNAME:1 UUID=47492bd7:08d1fd1c:418dad41:2aa7d77f
   > ```

   Name your arrays to your liking.
3. Use the following command to make sure you are mounting the right file systems:

   ```
   blkid /dev/md*
   ```

   for the `/etc/fstab` to contain these in such fashion:

   > ```
   > UUID=...
   > ```
4. The most important step you probably missed, I suspect, is updating your `initramfs`:

   ```
   update-initramfs -u
   ```

That should be it. I myself had the exact issue on the same system. If I missed a step or forgot on something, please leave a comment and I will edit this answer tomorrow morning.

Q&As:

> Where did this 127 come from?

As you forgot to update your `initramfs`, during boot the system does not know about your new array and by default starts naming it from the end (127).

> What's the difference between `/dev/md127` and `/dev/md127p1`?

- `/dev/md127` is the name of array
- `/dev/md127p1` is the name of the partition on the array

**Supplemental information by OP:**

As described above the `update-initramfs -u` did indeed seem to be crucial!  However, there turned out to a bit more tweaking possible, which I'll edit in here rather than in a different answer or comment:

After the steps above, I had `/dev/md0` and `/dev/md1p1`.  Curiously, looking at /proc/partitions I could see both a `/dev/md1` *and* a `/dev/md1p1`.   A bit of googling led me to suspect this was related to the default behaviour described in /proc/mdstat.conf:

```
# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers
```

and indeed adding an *non*-commented-out line

```
DEVICE partitions
```

meant I had just `/dev/md0` and `/dev/md1` after the next reboot.

(Looking at some older Debian machines with mdadm raid, I see they've all had an explicit `DEVICE partitions` line too, and I've never knowingly used or wanted to use mdadm's notion of "containers")